# scala regular expression to extract the fields clause in a sql statement

Tags: sql, regex

I want to develop a simple function to replace the fields clause in a sql statement

something like this

```
replaceFields("select  * from x", "f1")
// should return "select f1 from x"

replaceFields("select top 10 *   FROM x", "f1")
// should return "select top 10 f1   FROM x"

replaceFields("select top 10 f3, f4    FROM x", "f1, f2")
// should return "select top 10 f1, f2    FROM x"
```

I know this should be really simple, but I tried with a couple of regex but I just can't seem to find it

```
"select * from".replaceFirst("""select (\w+) from""", "count(*)")
// returns "select * from"

"select * from".replaceFirst("""select(\b(.*))\bfrom""", "count(*)")
// returns "count(*)"
```

but it didn't work...

Comment: "it didn't work"... what happened?

Comment: I added as a comment what the expression returned, right after each line... will edit it for clarity

Comment: Ah right sorry, I saw that for the first listing, but overlooked it for the second one

Comment: Here are the reasons why it doesn't work: the first one doesn't find the `*` because `\w` will only match `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. The second one **does** match, but the full match represents the whole string, so the whole string is replaced. I don't know how this works in your environment, but you need to replace the first capturing group instead. Also your second pattern will include the spaces in the capture.

Comment: your expected result `select top 10 count(*) from x` is not valid sql

Comment: @bw_üezi: I know, it was just an example to show that there could be something after the select that I don't want to include in the fields clause...

Answer (score 1):

You are correctly replacing

```
select(\b(.*))\bfrom
```

if you want to replace only the part between `select` and `from` you should not include those in the string to be replaced. Try

```
(?<=select\b)(.*?) from
```

and replace it with

```
count(*) from
```

EDIT:

It seems that you want to replace the list of columns from the table.

Assuming that every column name is after the list of keywords like `TOP` that you can find after the select statement, with related arguments I created this regex

```
(([^\s]+,\s+)*([^\s]+)\s+)from
```

It is based on the principle that the column name (which you want to replace) is either the *token* (allow me this word) before the `from` or it is separated with commas from the other tokens.

The case is then managed this way

```
token token, token FROM
      ^this is the starting point of substitution

token FROM
^this is the starting point
```

Replace the first group with what you want and you are fine. Test it [here](http://rubular.com/r/WEoFI8Enut)

Comment: it was just an example, there could be any list of fields there, I will edit it for clarity

Comment: very helful answer, the problem is that in the fields clause there may be some strange things like "select Upper(f1), f2 * 2, etc from table1"

Comment: Yup, I imagined that this could not work for everything. I think the best solution is to set up a set of keywords that can be found after the select statement and put them in a `|` list in the regex, like you did with `top` but with other pieces of code like `DISTINCT`

Comment: added distinct and all support

Comment: :) can't give you more than +1

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to gabber help, and a (not so) little bit of struggling with regular expressions, I came to this solution:

```
def replaceFields(sql: String, fields: String): String = {
  val parseSql = """(?imx)                #insensitive case, multiline, whitespaces and comments
    (^ select \s+ #(?:top \s+ \d+ \s+)?)  #m1: select clause and optional clauses
      (?:top \s+ \d+ \s+)?                #  top x clause (ignored match)
      (?:(?:distinct|all) \s+)?           #  distinct | all clause (ignored match)
    )
    (.+?)                                 #m2: the field clause I'm looking for, non greedy to leave spaces to match3
    (\s+ from \s+ .* $)                   #m3: the rest of the sql sentence, greedy spaces
  """.r
  val replace = "$1%s$3".format(fields)   // replace match2 with new fields
  parseSql.replaceFirstIn(sql, replace)
}
```

which gives:

```
scala> replaceFields("select * from x", "count(*)")
res1: String = select count(*) from x

scala> replaceFields("select top 24 f1, f2 from x", "f3, f4, f5")
res2: String = select top 24 f3, f4, f5 from x

scala> replaceFields("select  f1  from x", " f2,  f3 ")
res3: String = select   f2,  f3   from x

scala> replaceFields("select top 23 distinct f1, f2 from x", "f3, f4, f5")
res0: String = select top 23 distinct f3, f4, f5 from x
```

Comment: Glad you found your answer! Be careful, if you write `(\s+ from \s+ )` you are going to need two spaces before the from and three after it. `\s+` means 1+ spaces, then you add the one between `\s+` and `from`. Same thing after

Comment: in the (?imx) at the beginning, the "x" tells scala to ignore those whitespaces, so it's the same as writing (\s+from\s+.*$), I think my version is much more readable...

Comment: It is indeed, I just didn't know of this feature :)